# retrieving object based on its URI using RDFAlchemy and rdflib

Tags: python, orm, rdf, rdflib

I am using RDFAlchemy and rdflib graph for the source of the data, i.e. rdfalchemy.rdfSubject.db.
How can I have rdfalchemy map an object if I have its uri? calling the constructor with the uri creates an object but doesn't retrieve values of other properties from the graph. Using get_by(resUri='http://...') yields an AttributeError

```
class Book(rdfAlchemy.rdfSubject):
  rdf_type = BIBO.Book
  isbn = rdfalchemy.rdfSingle(BIBO.isbn10)
Book.get_by(resUri='') # AttributeError
b = Book(uri) #a book identified with uri exists in the data 
b.title #empty string
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess should be something like:

```
b = Book(URIRef(uri))
```

Comment: +1 Too bad it was never accepted.  This was (and still is) the right answer.  Note: I'm the creator of rdfAlchemy.